# Issue refreshing vault tokens in python with hvac

Tags: python, azure, flask, plotly-dash, hashicorp-vault

We have an hvac token that needs a lease renewed every hour so our app can talk to azure. Currently, the way the workflow works, is when the app starts up, it gets a client secret to talk to azure. Also at startup, a thread is started that refreshes the Vault token once every hour. Everything runs fine for an hour, until the token refresh happens, and we get an error saying  `session['_logged_in_user'] = result["id_token_claims] KeyError 'id_token_claims`

Here is the way the app currently runs. It uses a class called TokenKeeper to handle the act of initially grabbing tokens, getting client secrets from Vault, and refreshing any Vault tokens when their lease is up.

```
import os
import platform
import hvac
from hvac.api.auth_methods import Kubernetes
from time import sleep
import atexit
from dateutil import parser
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from my_app import CONFIG

# GLOBALS
# Get secrets
HOMEDIR = os.path.expanduser('~')
SECRET_LOCATION = f"{HOMEDIR}run/secrets/"
if platform.system()=='Windows':
    SECRET_LOCATION = f"{HOMEDIR}/run/secrets/"

# Get JWT
with open(f"{SECRET_LOCATION}kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token", 'rt') as f:
    JWT = f.read()

class TokenKeeper():

    def __init__(self, vault_url):
        self.vault_url = vault_url
        self.client = self.client_factory()

        
        atexit.register(self.revoke_token) 
       
        # Get first token
        self.get_client_secret()
       
        # Sleep until we get a secret
        while self.secret is None:
            CONFIG.LOGGER.debug('TokenKeeper is waiting for the first secret')
            sleep(1)
       
        # Start the loop
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug('Token keeper is Starting Loop')
        self._start_loop()


    resp     = None  # Request reponse from vault
    token    = None  # the response data from the last client.read request
    lease    = None  # Informaiton about the lease
    _secret  = None  
    last_req = None  # the last time a token was issued, ie. lease['data']['issue_time']
    next_req = None  # when the token expires, ie. lease['data']['expire_time']

    def client_factory(self):
        client = hvac.Client(url=self.vault_url)
        resp = Kubernetes(client.adapter).login(
            role="my_role",
            jwt = JWT,
            mount_point='k8s',
            use_token=True
        )
        sleep(2)
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'Client Factory logged into Vault. Response was: {resp}')
        self.resp = resp
        return client

    @property
    def secret(self):
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug('Something asked the TokenKeeper for the secret')
        return self._secret

    # Function to revoke the token. Pass this to at exit on teardown
    def revoke_token(self):
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper was asked to revoke the lease for a token')
        client = self.client
        client.revoke_token(self.token)
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper revoked the lease for this token: {self.token}')
        # client.logout(False)
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper logged out of vault')
       

    # Function to renew a token.
    def renew_token(self):
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper was asked to renew a token')
        client = self.client
        client.renew_token(self.token['data'])
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper renewed this token: {self.token}')
        # client.logout(False)      


    # Function to get a client secret
    def get_client_secret(self):
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug('Something asked the TokenKeeper to ask Vault for a new secret')
        client = self.client

        # Ask vault to create a new client secret.
        self.token = client.read('path/to/creds')
        self.lease = client.sys.read_lease(self.token['lease_id'])

        if self.token is not None:
            client.revoke_token(self.token)

        self.issue_dt  = parser.parse(self.lease['data']['issue_time'])
        self.expiry_dt = parser.parse(self.lease['data']['expire_time'])
        self._secret   = self.token['data']['client_secret']

        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'The lease data for the new secret is {self.lease}')
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper has a new secret {self._secret}')
        # client.logout(False)
        return True

    def _start_loop(self):
        update_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._renew_loop)
        update_thread.daemon = True
        CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper is starting a thread to renew a secret')
        update_thread.start()
   
    def _renew_loop(self, eager=0):
        while True:
            current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
           
            # Sleep until 'eager' minutes to expiration
            sleep_amount = self.expiry_dt-current_time
            sleep_amount = sleep_amount.total_seconds() - (60*eager)
           
            #sleep(sleep_amount)
            sleep(30)

            # Renew the token
            CONFIG.LOGGER.debug(f'TokenKeeper about to renew a token')
            self.renew_token()
```

Inside the app, we then call this class by doing the following.

```
from tokenkeeper import TokenKeeper
tk = TokenKeeper(vault_url = CONFIG.VAULT_URL)
```

As I mentioned, this works fine at start up and until the vault token lease needs to be renewed. I will mention as a group we are newer to using Vault to store azure client secrets, so if there is a better way to do this we are all ears. Thanks!

Comment: Is your relevant code in the stack trace at `client.renew_token(self.token['data'])`? Is the policy attached to the token authorized to renew the token lease? Is the token renewable? Is the token being revoked prior to renewal?